# Comparing proportion of population test success on a common variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

I have two equal populations, A and B, with two different distributions of a variable V. For each population, only the mean and SD metrics of V are known.

Assuming that x% of A population pass a test on how high their V score is, what is the y% of B population that also pass it?

Thank you.

Comment: If population A and B are truly different there is no *a priori* reason to expect that the percentage of A who pass the test has anything to do with the percentage of B who pass the test. Take an extreme example in which I give Japanese and American students an English language examination. There would be little reason to suspect that the passing rate among Japanese students tells me anything about the passing rate among American students.

Comment: I think that even in this case we can infer the passing rate of Americans, using a V variable "metric of ability in the English language". I generalized in the question though, in my specific test, we can a priori assume that anyone with e.g. >5 in the V automatically passes the test.

Comment: I hope we aren't talking past one another. My point was not in reference to the threshold used for passing but rather the idea that it is entirely possible that, when you have two different populations, the application of an equivalent threshold and determination of the % passed in one population will be in no way informative regarding the passing rate in another, distinct population.

Comment: There are no external factors in my case, I don't think there's such a problem. All we need to care about is the proportion of the population for whose their V is equal or greater than the threshold. I made an image of an example where 50% of A pass, and we want to know how many of B pass. http://i.cubeupload.com/KcImnI.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With the information given in the question, the answer is simply "there is no way to tell". Just because you know the means and SDs of the distribution of V in populations A and B tells you **nothing** about how they are related. On a slightly more conceptual level, you have the marginal distributions of V given A and V given B and you want to know if there is any way to go from one to the other. The answer is yes if you know the joint distribution---but you don't. If the distribution of V in each population is independent, you can tell **nothing**. If there is a correlation, then perhaps you can move from marginals to joint if you know/assume as specific copula structure and [Sklar's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar%27s_theorem). But with just the information you provide, there is no way to tell anything about one population from the other.